# asp problem, expected '('

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I get this error when viewing the page in Internet explorer
Webpage error details

```
 Message: Expected '(' 
    Line: 152
    Char: 4 
    Code: 0

    <script>/* <![CDATA[ */qmad.mwidths=new Object();if(qmad.bvis.indexOf("qm_mwidths_a(b.cdiv,o);")==-1)qmad.bvis+="qm_mwidths_a(b.cdiv,o);";;function qm_mwidths_a(sub,item){var z;if((z=window.qmv)&&(z=z.addons)&&(z=z.match_widths)&&!z["on"+qm_index(sub)])return;var ss;if(!item.settingsid){var v=item;while((v=v.parentNode)){if(v.className.indexOf("qmmc")+1){item.settingsid=v.id;break;}}}ss=qmad[item.settingsid];if(!ss)return;if(!ss.mwidths_active)return;if(qm_a(item.parentNode)){var t=0;t+=qm_getcomputedstyle(sub,"padding-left","paddingLeft");t+=qm_getcomputedstyle(sub,"padding-right","paddingRight");t+=qm_getcomputedstyle(sub,"border-left-width","borderLeftWidth");t+=qm_getcomputedstyle(sub,"border-right-width","borderRightWidth");var adj=0;adj=item.getAttribute("matchwidthadjust");if(adj)adj=parseInt(adj);if(!adj||isNaN(adj))adj=0;sub.style.width=(item.offsetWidth-t+adj)+"px";var a=sub.childNodes;for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){if(a[i].tagName=="A")a[i].style.whiteSpace="normal";}}};function qm_getcomputedstyle(obj,sname,jname){var v;if(document.defaultView&&document.defaultView.getComputedStyle)v=document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(obj,null).getPropertyValue(sname);else  if(obj.currentStyle)v=obj.currentStyle[jname];if(v&&!isNaN(v=parseInt(v)))return v;else return 0;}/* ]]> */</script>


    148:    <%
    149:    UserIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")
    150:    If UserIPAddress = "" Then 
    151:    UserIPAddress = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
    152:    end if
    153:    
    154:    
    155: IF Left(UserIPAddress,11) = "192.168.130" or Left(UserIPAddress,10) = "236.234.11"  then
    156:    %>  
    157:      
    158:    <%  
    159:    IF ucase(request.querystring("go"))="" then  
    160:        go="HOME"  
    161:    ELSE  
    162:        go = ucase(request.querystring("go"))
    163:    END IF
    164:    
    165:    IF ucase(request.querystring("rdate"))="" then
    166:        rdate = FormatDateTime(now(), 2)
    167:    ELSE
    168:        rdate = ucase(request.querystring("rdate"))
    169:    END IF
    170;    
    171:    If not(IsDate(rdate)) Then
    172:        rdate = FormatDateTime(now(), 2)
    173:    End If
    174:    %>
```

This is the view source code/runtime

```
150:    <script> 
151:  <!--
152:  if request.querystring("rdate")<>"" then
153:   rdate=request.querystring("rdate")
154:  else
155:   rdate= now()
156:   end if
157:   
158:  function querySt(ji) {
159:  hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
160:  gy = hu.split("&");
161:  for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++) {
162:  ft = gy[i].split("=");
163:  if (ft[0] == ji) {
164:   return ft[1];
165: }
166: }
167: }
168: var rundate = querySt("rdate");
169: 
170: if request.querystring("rdate")<>"" then
171:   rundate=request.querystring("rdate")
172: else
173:   rdate= now()
174:   end if
175:   
176: document.write(rdate);
177: document.write("<br>");
178: -->
179: </script>
```

Comment: This is not the whole file (you are missing at least one END IF), and you didn't indicate what line 159 is.

Comment: Since it complains about an error on line 159, and there aren't that many lines in that sample of code … I'm guessing that isn't the whole thing. Line numbers would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Has anyone ever seen a VBScript file that was properly formatted? I've written a couple myself, its not that hard.

Comment: Actually the formatting was okay, I think it was just in there as a blockquote or something rather than code. It looks fine to me now.

Comment: where is the missing end if, and instead of complaining about how i wrote my question and marking it down. You could have just asked for more information and i would have provided it to the people trying to help me.

Comment: You should never debug JavaScript errors by looking at the serverside code. Look at the view source.

Comment: thank you I will post the view source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NEWprogrammer: You seem to be mixing ASP with JavaScript (in second code snippet, Ln. 150 - 179). Both of your `if request.querystring` blocks in that code should be in ASP delimiters, `<% %>`, which will take care of that specific syntax error you're getting.

It appears as if you don't even need that whole second block at all though since it doesn't look like you ever use it again and the `rundate` `GET` parameter is already checked and set in ASP, you could probably just comment out or remove that whole second block.

Comment: thanks, this was the first time i have worked with regular asp.